# List Comprehension - selecting elements from different lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I find the below piece of code a bit confusing.

```
l1 = ['left', 'up', 'front']
l2 = ['right', 'down', 'back']

opposites=filter(lambda word: len(word[0]) > 3 and len(word[1]) >3, zip(l1,l2))
```

The above code is supposed to get words from the two lists that have a length of at least 3 letters and add them to a list (opposites) using list comprehension.

I do not understand why we have word[0] and word[1]..."word" here to me is 1 list and we get the first two elements or something...

I do not have much experience with list comprehension but could somebody explain to me this part in more detail...

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry bad wording!

Comment: Ignore question!

Answer (score 0):

To begin, this expression is not a list comprehension. It is just a use of the built-in functions in python.

But I agree that this code is a bit confusing. Maybe a rapid review of the functions will do the job.

Firstly, the function `zip(l1, l2)` aggregates the elements of your 2 lists:

```
zip(l1, l2) = [ ('left', 'right'), ('up', 'down'), ('front', 'back') ]
```

Secondly, the keyword `lambda` and all the first parameter of the function `filter` are here to simplify the definition of a small function as you can replace the following statement :

```
lambda word: len(word[0]) > 3 and len(word[1]) >3
```

By this one, easier to understand:

```
def pred(word):              # e.g. word = ("left", "right")
    elem_l1 = word[0]  
    elem_l2 = word[1]
    return len(elem_l1) > 3 and len(elem_l2) > 3
```

Finally the function `filter(a, b)` will go through all the elements of `b` (e.g. the zipped lists) and will launch your function `a` (e.g. the lambda function) on all the elements. And based on the result of your function. It will select the elements to return and to store in your variable `opposites`.

So in the end, the code you have shown could be replaced by the following one:

```
l1 = ['left', 'up', 'front']
l2 = ['right', 'down', 'back']
opposites = []

def pred(word):              # e.g. word = ("left", "right")
    elem_l1 = word[0]  
    elem_l2 = word[1]
    return len(elem_l1) > 3 and len(elem_l2) > 3

for word in zip(l1, l2):
    if pred(word):
        opposites.append(word)
```

PS: That is not exactly true as the function `filter` does not return a list. But if you want to use it as such, you have to embrace your filtered statement with the function `list()`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I did not mean list comprehension. I was referring to zip...

Answer (score 0):

Other answer from @eliottness breaks down the filter and lambda operations nicely.  However, OP wants to do this in a list comprehension.  The basic format of list comprehension is

- what you want for the result.  (In this case a tuple)
- what is the source of the input.  (In this case it is a tuple from a zip)
- what are the conditions on the input.  (In this case it is both the members have minimal length.

That said, this works:

```
l1 = ['left', 'up', 'front']
l2 = ['right', 'down', 'back']

opposites = [(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(l1, l2) if len(a) > 3 and len(b) > 3]

print(opposites)
```

#### Output:

```
[('left', 'right'), ('front', 'back')]
```